Passing required args of same type to super constructor
Imagine an abstract superclass with several required (and final) properties of the same type
How do you pass the args in its subtype safely?
This is not safe since you can confuse the order by mistake (e.g. calling super("value B", "value A", "value C") instead)
    abstract class AbstractSupertype {
        private final String propertyOne;
        private final String propertyTwo;
        private final String propertyThree;
        protected AbstractSupertype (String propertyOne, String propertyTwo, String propertyThree) {
            this.propertyOne = propertyOne;
            this.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
            this.propertyThree = propertyThree;
        }
        abstract void doX();
    }

    class ConcreteSupertype extends {
        ConcreteSupertype() {
            super("value A", "value B", "value C");
        }
        @Override
        void doX() {
            System.out.println("Doing X...");
        }
    }

I guess I could use a builder as a container for those args, but it would be an unconventional usage of the builder pattern (some could argue a misusage). For one thing, it doesn't build anything, I never call build() on it
I guess I could just rename the nested class to something like AbstractSupertypePropertyContainer, but that would definitely raise a few eyebrows of my teammates
If declaring some nested property container is the only way, I guess it boils down to naming. Properties? Configuration? It's not straightforward to pick a name that's not already picked by other standard or third-party type (and I want to avoid any confusion)
    protected AbstractSupertype(Builder builder) {
        this.propertyOne = builder.propertyOne;
        this.propertyTwo = builder.propertyTwo;
        this.propertyThree = builder.propertyThree;
    }
    // a nested Builder class

    ConcreteSupertype() {
        super(createBuilder());
    }
    private static AbstractSupertype.Builder createBuilder() {
        AbstractSupertype.Builder builder = AbstractSupertype.builder();
        builder.withPropertyOne("value A");
        builder.withPropertyTwo("value B");
        builder.withPropertyThree("value C");
        return builder;
    }

Note. I'm refactoring some code. Now, our abstract supertype declares a few abstract "getters" (e.g. getPropertyOne()), and its subtypes override them to return static hard-coded strings (they override a few behavioral abstract methods as well so they have their purpose). I believe it's wrong to override methods to pass state for your supertype initialization and you should pass that state in super constructors instead. But those args are all strings. I could simply add setters in the supertype code and invoke them in the subtype constructors, but that would mandate mutability for those properties which is suboptimal

This question has no relation to actual inheritance or class constructors. It boils down to "how do I understand method parameter order if not by method parameter type?"

As to your proposed solution of a builder, how do you ensure that you're passing the right value into the right builder method? You've shifted the problem but haven't really solved it. If you weren't confident about filling in the right method parameters, why would you be confident about using the right method?

@Flater because the builder methods are named after the properties. Surely, you can purposefully pass some BS anyway, but that would be your choice. The problem is confusing the order of args by mistake (e.g. super("value B", "value A", "value C")). Remember how AssertJ addressed the issue of confusing the order of expected and actual values in JUnit's OOB assertions

Typically you would have a separate type for each of those properties. For example if string is an email: create an Email class. If it is description, create Description class, etc. That way it is unlikely to make a mistake, and you don't need a fancy builders.

@freakish that would create a ton of "dumb" types that simply wrap string properties. Not optimal

There’s an obvious simple way (call the superclass constructor from your subclass constructor, which you must do anyway in some way, and you can use arbitrary complicated ways to it.

@SergeyZolotarev on the contrary. That's very optimal. Yes, you write couple of classes. So what? Are you worried you will run out of disk space? Or that saving those 15minutes of writing code matters? That's hardly a cost for the benefits it brings, which is strong typing.

@freakish: There is a natural limit on this though. Yes, this is how you can combat primitive obsession. No, that can't just be extended all the way down to never having two identically typed properties on an object, that's several bridges too far. Take a simple example: first name and last name.

@Flater I don't see any reason not to have separate types for first and last name. You have such distinction in your business logic. And yet you don't want it to be distinguished in code, because? The only reasonable argument is if it affects performance (e.g. if abstractions are not free in your language). Otherwise it is laziness. Also, why do you think most languages go down that road? Why we no longer use say ints for datetime like in good old C times.

@freakish we have 8K+ types in our key module already and there's an obvious resistance from the lead when it comes to adding even more types (and wrapping each string property would make the number of types skyrocket)

@SergeyZolotarev 8k+ types? Wow, that's huge. I'm pretty sure you are solving the wrong problem here. That's unmanageable. Regardless of the strategy.

@freakish: "Why we no longer use say ints for datetime" That's not the point being made. A datetime type constructor takes in three ints: year, month, day (I'm referring to .NET here). OP's question is about any constructor which has more than one parameter of the same type. Your initial comment and the one in response to mine seem to both be arguing that you need separate Year, Month and Day types around those individual int values, so as to provide type safety and prevent OP from confusing the order of the constructor parameters.

@freakish If that is indeed what you're suggesting here: "I don't see any reason not to have separate types" The reason to not do so would be the absolute boatload of types that you need to add to a codebase in order to get it working the way you're suggesting it should. Your take is decidedly different from what primitive obsession generally refers to, to the point of extreme dogma. This shouldn't become turtles all the way down (reference).

In languages without named parameters, the solution to this kind of problem is one of (1) use wrapper types/newtypes so that the type system can check this, (2) use parameter objects or builders, or (3) suck it up. In any case, techniques like integration tests or code reviews could help ensure correctness, and some IDEs show inlay hints for param names. In modern Java (or Kotlin, Scala) I'd encourage using newtypes. In classic Java, just suck it up. In C#, anonymous subclasses for parameter objects are common-ish.

@SergeyZolotarev >8,000 types is indeed such a large number that it makes me think you're succumbing to the XY problem here. 8,000 types is way too many for any developer to be able to understand, use, maintain and keep adequately distinct from one another (without monstrously long names on top of that). Developer confusion is inevitable and no amount of coding patterns (other than separate codebases) is going to adequately resolve this issue. You're asking for a stronger camel but you really shouldn't be trying to stack that many straws on any creature's back.

@Flater you still didn't give any reason beyond "this is lots of code". Yes, it is. So what? That's the real dogma here. "OP's question is about any constructor which has more than one parameter of the same type." Yes, these are the same type because they were defined like that. I don't see anything indicating that these are the same thing. In fact I mentioned Emails and Description, and OP did not protest to that. These are literally different things, regardless of how you represent them internally. And that's really what abstractions are about.

"A datetime type constructor takes in three ints:" It is irrelevant. Why don't you use a function that returns a timestamp int instead? Because that's what datetime is.

In what way is this problem any different from accidentally messing up the order of arguments to any function?

@freakish You're really missing the mark here on what the question is. Having multiple constructor parameters with the same type is the core of the question being asked here. Calling it irrelevant suggest you're focusing on something entirely different.

@Flater datetime's constructor is irrelevant to the discussion. It is part of the std, and nothing can be done about that. The point I'm making, for the third time, is that strong typing is useful, even when it is a tiny wrapper around int. Which seems to be acknowledged by most people. It has nothing to do with datetime's constructor.

Folks, one more thing. The passed strings are used in the super constructor. I really can't use setters — even if I sacrifice immutability (I considered that)

@freakish sorry, it's actually 4k+. Though, it's still a lot

My first instinct was to create a new class representing the concept embodied by  properties 1, 2, and 3. This only works if those properties are cohesive. For the sake of argument, let's pretend like those 3 properties are cohesive, so we encapsulate them in their own type, which we will call Foo.
Now your abstract class has a nice clean constructor:
protected AbstractSupertype(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

And the concrete sub type does too:
public ConcreteSupertype() {
    super(new Foo("property 1", "property 2", "property 3"));
}

In your trivial example, the concrete type is passing hard-coded values up to the abstract parent. Taking your example code literally, I don't see how introducing a new type to encapsulate those 3 properties is very beneficial. Your original concern is something like "what if I pass property 2 followed by property 1, thereby reversing the order of parameter arguments?" Moving the properties into their own type just pushes that problem into another class.
Consider this example with the new parameter object:
super(new Foo("property 1", "property 3", "property 2"));
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^

You can still pass things out of order on accident without the compiler complaining about it, which might result in a runtime error.
Adding a builder can help alleviate this problem, but it's not an automatic decision. Does introducing a builder make the application easier to reason about and maintain? This is impossible to judge without seeing the real code. This might be impossible for you to judge by yourself. You might want to run this by some coworkers to see if they agree. "Good code," after all, is in the eye of the beholder. Each person has their own view about what is easy to read and maintain.
A few notes about the builder presented in question:

Builders are also meant to be used in conjunction with method chaining where appropriate. The createBuilder() method can be refactored to:
return AbstractSupertype.builder()
    .withPropertyOne("value A")
    .withPropertyTwo("value B")
    .withPropertyThree("value C");

Again, this can be seen as a matter of taste, however with these particular lines of code, I would expect method chaining to be utilized, which cuts down on the clutter in the code. I don't need to see "builder" repeated 5 times to understand what the code is doing, and seeing those extra characters can make it more difficult to see what is happening.

I would be very surprised, and immediately suspicious of a code smell, if I encountered a builder being created with hard-coded values in a child class constructor, which is passed up to the parent class constructor where the parent class assigns individual values from the builder to its own properties. It feels like the code is conflating the Joshua Bloch Builder Pattern with a parameter object. This definitely feels over-engineered and obfuscated.


The only other design option I can think of is to create a type for each property, so you pass the three properties as 3 different types in the constructor, but again, you just move the problem around. You cannot avoid runtime checks on the string format if you expect it to conform to some structure:
class PropertyOne {
    private final String value

class PropertyTwo {
    private final String value

class PropertyThree {
    private final String value

Now your abstract type gets three strongly typed parameters:
protected AbstractSupertype(PropertyOne one, PropertyTwo two, PropertyThree three)

And your concrete type becomes:
public ConcreteType() {
    super(new PropertyOne("one"), new PropertyTwo("two"), new PropertyThree("three"));

Again, you can still mix things up because you are using strings. There is nothing stopping you from using:
super(new PropertyOne("one"), new PropertyTwo("three"), new PropertyThree("two"));
//                                             ^^^^^                       ^^^

The semantics of what these three properties mean in your application can help inform a proper design, but the fact is if you need 3 strings, you need 3 strings. At some point you are going to either hard code those strings, take them from user input, the database, or configuration. Consuming code will need to perform runtime checks on the values and/or format of those strings to ensure they conform to your programs assumptions.
When there is no clear way to prevent mistakes with passing values out of order, then my best advice is to make sure the program is easy to understand for everyone, not just you. For that, you will need input from your teammates.

Thank you! What if all properties are required, and yet the client failed to set one of the properties in the builder method chain? Should build() throw? Assume the properties are some ids that can't be provided with a reasonable default value

@SergeyZolotarev, the pattern often recommends default values, but the "builder pattern" police won't come knocking on your door if you decide no sensible default exists and throw an exception. It really comes back to readability and maintainability.

In any language I know, to get an instance of a class, someone must call its constructor, and the constructor must call the superclass constructor. So that tells you how to write the constructor, no way around it.
And then to get an instance, you call the constructor or some function calling the constructor for you. That’s up to you how you do it. It doesn’t change the fact that your constructor must call its superclas onstructor.
I am just amazed how complicated you want to make a very simple task.

That completely misses the point of my question (which is ensuring the supertype properties are set safely)

As much as I agree on the overall conclusion to just use constructors as they were designed to be used, it feels like this answer is not addressing the actual problem that is leading OP down this path: parameter order confusion. Not saying there's a solution to it, but by not addressing it this answer feels like it's missing the mark a bit.
